# Performing an action upon DHCP Lease (Microsoft)

Tags: dhcp

I have a need to detect machines added to a network to attempt to force installation of software.

Machines that are joined to the domain - no problem, I use the login script or group policy.

It's machines that don't join the domain that I am interested in and I *think* that detecting when they request and are allocated an IP address is the point at which they first appear on the network and when I am in the best position to take some action.

Does anyone know of a way to trigger an action on DHCP lease allocation on Windows DHCP?

Thanks!